# Not all values are being set to 0 in this array?

Tags: c++

I am essentially trying to create an array and having the user enter in a square matrix. For some reason, not all of the values are being set to 0, and I am unsure why. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row, col, n;
    cout<<"Enter a positive odd integer above 1:   ";
    cin>>n;
    int mgcsqre[n][n] = {0};
}
```

Comment: Note that variable length arrays (VLAs) and not part of the C++ standard, but rather are an extension provided by gcc. This may be part of the reason for the behavior you are witnessing.

Comment: How are you determining whether the values were set to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should know that arrays of variable length are just a GCC extension and not part of C or C++ standard. You can take a look at the GCC [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html):

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an
>   extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays are
>   declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is
>   not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of
>   declaration and deallocated when the block scope containing the
>   declaration exits.

Therefore, the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 5;

    int mgcsqre[n][n] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            std::cout << mgcsqre[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

is going to compile perfectly with GCC, but will produce following error when compiled with CLANG:

> error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Now, the above code compiled with GCC will produce the following result:

```
0 32536 -1273401536 32536 -1270477024 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

Why does it output some garbage values? Because behavior is undefined by the C++ standard itself.

If you try to compile the equivalent code in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 5;

    int mgcsqre[n][n] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mgcsqre[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you will get the following error:

> error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

because of:

> C99 §6.7.8 [Initialization]
>
> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown
>   size or an object type that is not a variable length array type.

So, what would be the right way to initialize variable-length arrays? There are two options:

1. using [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)
2. using traditional for loop to traverse all the elements and initialize them to 0

Answer (score 1):

The values of the array are never read. Therefore whether they are initialised or not is not observable. As per the as-if rule, the compiler is allowed to change the behaviour of the program as long as those changes are not observable. Therefore the compiler is allowed to not initialise the array.

P.S. the program is ill-formed in C++ because `n` is not a compile time constant and therefore not allowed to be used as the size of an automatic array.

Comment: I can reproduce his error when reading from the array. GCC 9.2. https://godbolt.org/z/zFWB6x

Comment: @BradyDean In that case the behaviour is probably due to VLA whose behaviour is not specified by C++ language.

Comment: more than likely. As far as I can tell from GCC's website, its extension supports VLAs are they are in C. It might not play nicely with C++'s different forms of initialization.